# Cannot add data to SQL Server Database from my ASP website form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webformsmvp

I'm pretty new to SQL Databases & C# language, I can't add data to my SQL Database from my web application despite doing everything correctly? I'm currently training in Azure SQL & C# & have been using the following training video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POWm4EfU9bA

I'm using MS Visual Studio and MS SQL Server Management Studio, I'm also using Azure Web + SQL service and I have opened up the firewall allowing my client IP address through.

Can anyone work out, from my code, why I my data from my webform isn't being added to my database? Here is my coding which "apparently" adds data to my SQL database from the form located in my front end web application:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace bluecitywebapplication
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
            {
                Label1.Text = ("Great job!");

            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection stormconn = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:bluecitydb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;");
            {
                SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("EXEC dbo.InsertFullname @Fullname", stormconn);
                insert.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fullname", TextBox1.Text);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox2.Text);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox3.Text);


                stormconn.Open();
                insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                stormconn.Close();

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = ("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your connection string has an instance of the database.  Open SQL Server Management Studio and use instance of the database in the connection string.  I would recommend using windows credentials which is what SSMS is probably using.  Your connection string should look like this : "Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net\MyInstance;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Integrated Security=true;Connection Timeout=30;"

Comment: In your command `EXEC dbo.InsertFullname @Fullname` leave away the `@Fullname`. You are correctly adding that parameter in the next line. Also add a line `insert.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` to make sure your parameter is properly handled.

Comment: I've tried this, but the it's saying that the second `CommandType` `Does not exist in the current context` but is suggesting `System.Data.CommandType`.

Answer (score -1):

sorry, I apologize for the mistake, I thought that you are facing connection issue in your question. I read the code carefuly i found there is issue in the code of executing procedure. I updated the code.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"))
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("InsertFullname", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("Fullname", TextBox1.Text));

        command.Connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Connection.Close();
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it's coming up with this code in the bottom line:
`The program '[14444] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).`

Comment: Right, I've inserted your suggested code and it's saying that the second `CommandType` **does not exist In the current content (CS0103)**. It suggests "System.Data.CommandType" though? Is this the one?

Comment: This is the last line
`The program '[8104] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).`

Comment: This is the code I now have:
`SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("InsertFullname", stormconn);
                insert.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: @BlueCityCapitalInvestments : Please update the code in your question to reflect the current status. Also: set a breakpoint and/or write to a log file at certain code points to learn where exactly the code fails.

Comment: No but it's worth mentioning that I'm using v 15.9.6 so some of the command syntaxes will be different to the ones you're suggesting. :)

Comment: I dont think that due to different version of visual studio, system namespaces will changed. For all version of visual studios, c# code and namespaced available will be same. Thank you.

Comment: Nearly keeled over in shock, it's finally working. I used my code and now it'd decided it's going to do as it's told.

Comment: Thank you. So, could you please accept my answer. Thank you.